# How can a post be converted to community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, posts, convert

How do I convert a post to a community wiki post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is an answer, edit it and tick the box.

If it is a question: you can't, not any more. Flag it for moderator attention and a moderator can do it for you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for helping. I have flagged my post.